# Add links to typedefs in doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

In the following example, the generated doxygen file will only turn #mystruct and mystruct into links to the definition of mystruct.  Is there anyway to have the same behavior for mytype, myenum and FIRST_ELEMENT or is that an inherent limitation of doxygen?

```
typedef enum myenum {
  FIRST_ELEMENT,  /**< Some example. */
  SECOND_ELEMENT,  /**< Some other example. */
} myenum;

typedef int16_t mytype;  /**< some example */

typedef struct mystruct {
    mytype x;   /**< my member */
} mystruct;


/**
 * @brief       My test function.
 *
 * This function uses #mytype, #mystruct and #myenum.
 *
 * @param[in]   x   input 1.
 * @param[in]   y   input 2.
 * @param[in]   z   input 3 expected to be #FIRST_ELEMENT.
 */
void foo(mytype x, mystruct y, myenum z);
```

Comment: I tried this out, (adding only `/** \file */` to the start of the file), and all links to mytype, myenum, and FIRST_ELEMENT appeared. This was with doxygen 1.8.17.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake: what happened is that I had my functions grouped together with defgroup and not my type declarations. Apparently not having defgroup around the types allowed the struct definition to still be visible and linked to in the html, but not the other types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that I described actually works as expected.

Documenting the mistake I was making here in case others make the same.

My mistake was that in the code base I had (not the example I showed here) I had my functions grouped together with defgroup and not my type declarations. Apparently not having defgroup around the types allowed the struct definition to still be visible and linked to in the html, but not the other types.